# How to limit the request body size when using GKE Gateway controller?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-gateway-api

I'm on GKE and I want to migrate from an nginx Ingress to a Gateway + HttpRoute. I was using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` annotation to limit the size of the request body at the load balancer level.

I did not find a way to do that in the [HttpRoute API Spec](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/references/spec/#gateway.networking.k8s.io%2Fv1beta1.HTTPRoute).

Is there a way to do this when using a Gateway instead of an Ingress?

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes Gateway API and HTTPRoute do not directly support the [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size](http://nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size) annotation for controlling the request body size at the load balancer level. This means that if you need to control the request body size, you will need to use a different method, such as using a filter or a custom ingress controller.